# What is the best way to iterate through a filtered set of properties of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, linq, javascript-objects

I'm having to write a lot of

```
for ( var prop in obj ) 
{
   if ( condition(prop) ) 
   {
      // ... 
   }
}
```

-type sections in my production code. The following are a few examples directly copy-pasted.

(1)

```
    for ( var region in this.DealsByRegion ) // iterate through regions
    {
        if ( this.RegionsChecked[region] === true ) // if region is checked in table   
        {
            num_deal_opportunities += region.NumOpportunities;
            total_deal_percentage += region[dealName] * region.NumOpportunities;
        }    

    }
```

(2)

```
for ( var deal_name in this.DealsChecked ) 
{
    if ( this.DealsChecked[deal_name] === true ) 
    {
        offer_data.push({ value: deal_percentages[deal_name], 
                          color: this.ColorStack[(this.ColorStack.length + i) % this.ColorStack], 
                          highlight: this.HighlightColor, 
                          label: deal_name });
    }       
}
```

and of course many cases of

```
for ( var thisguy in theseguys ) 
{
   if (theseguys.hasOwnProperty(thisguy)
   {
     // ... 
   }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this more elegant and compact. I tried writing a LINQ-like Where clause

```
// helper function for iterating through a filtered set of properties
Object.prototype.PropsWhere = function ( cond ) 
{
    var propsWhere = [];
    for ( var prop in this ) 
    {
        if ( cond(prop) ) 
        {
            propsWhere.push(prop);  
        }   
    }
    return propsWhere;
}
```

but when I tried to use it I realized it actually made everything ***less*** compact and readable and of course I have to then deal with a new `this` and yada-yada.

How should I be approaching these situations?

Comment: What you're doing seems fine, everything else will probably just complicate it, like `Object.keys(this.DealsByRegion).filter(Number).forEach(function() {...` etc.

Comment: Are `this.DealsByRegion` and `this.DealsChecked` objects or arrays?

Comment: @adeneo beware, `[0, 1, 2].filter(Number); // [1, 2]`

Comment: If you add some sample json data we might be able to write more concise loops to give you what you want.  I don't want to make up hypothetical data which doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: does this `for ( var region in this.DealsByRegion ) ...    num_deal_opportunities += region.NumOpportunities` really work? i mean region in is a single property, a string, not an object. how can you use the string as an object without the surrounding object of the stringed property? or do you have changed the string object and added `NumOpportunities` as property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're finding that you're having to write a lot of conditional statements that iterate over the properties of your objects - you might want to re-examine your schema.

Using your regions example:

```
for ( var region in RegionsChecked ) // iterate through checked regions
{
    num_deal_opportunities += region.NumOpportunities;
    total_deal_percentage += region[dealName] * region.NumOpportunities;
}
```

In this way your containers only contain references to the objects you care about - rather than creating "meta-containers" that tell you the id of the objects you care about.

Not sure if this is feasible with your infrastructure - but see if you can create containers of the objects you want - rather than intermediary containers which tell you which objects you want in other containers.

Another approach would be to tag the objects themselves with the "checked" property/field.  But, my guess is that you don't want to pollute your objects with something as transient as whether they're currently checked or not.